# Can't execute a while clause in SQL Server with Dbeaver

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, dbeaver

I am trying to execute a loop `while` in Dbeaver with SQL Server, but the statement keeps loading and does not execute it. I just want to print the word **'ok!'** 3 times.

I'm not sure if it's a loop problem, a Dbeaver problem, or another.

Can anyone help please?

My code:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 3
BEGIN
   PRINT 'ok!';
   
END;
```

[Screenshot from Dbeaver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyOz1.png)

Comment: `@cnt` never increments, so this loop will never finish. It will never yield control back to the system to let it even show the first `ok` string. Anyway, 99 times out of a 100, if you're writing a loop in SQL at all you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: You don't increment @cnt at the end of the loop.

Comment: Before `END`, add something like `SET @cnt = @cnt+1`

Comment: I'd love to know *why* you want a `WHILE` loop, you almost never need one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@cnt` never increments, so this loop will never finish. It will never yield control back to the system to let it even show the first `ok` string. You need to add this:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 3
BEGIN
   PRINT 'ok!';
   Set @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

Anyway, 99 times out of a 100, if you're writing a loop in SQL at all you're doing something very wrong. SQL really wants to operate on whole **sets** at a time, not individual items in the sets via loops.